# Neural network structure for matrices as output with keras+tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, matrix, neural-network

I am implementing a neural network to predict a 25x25 matrix from an input-vector. So this is a regression task. So far, I transformed the matrix into a vector, but only the first 10x10, making my output a 100-vector. And I built a simple fully connected network with keras and tensorflow and acheived good results.

My problem is now that after 10x10, 0 start to appear in my data and my method stops working.

What I did so far:

```
m1 = 10
m2 = 10
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(m1*m2))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.003), metrics=['mae'])
history = model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train_scaled, validation_split=0.15, epochs=50, batch_size=10)
```

Input data looks something like this (but with more data rows and normalized). Example with 3 data rows

```
x_train = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Output data. Example with 1 data row

```
y_train_matrix = [[   20.342,    89.554,   164.455,   242.08 ,   322.665,   403.907,
          486.647,   579.094,   669.527,   758.817,   847.453,   939.866,
         1024.576,  1120.246,  1219.249,  1296.751,  1396.886,  1492.008,
         1593.679,  1698.025,  1831.984,  1904.128,  2076.412,  2229.641,
         2442.131],
       [   44.229,   116.312,   193.306,   272.943,   355.677,   438.503,
          522.216,   616.599,   706.206,   797.614,   885.53 ,   980.381,
         1076.048,  1169.029,  1266.363,  1362.49 ,  1467.727,  1569.968,
         1676.168,  1784.434,  1868.041,  1972.941,  2152.995,  2306.2  ,
         2542.948],
       [  106.55 ,   181.582,   261.911,   344.737,   430.707,   516.574,
          614.379,   708.778,   803.058,   894.618,   991.723,  1085.575,
         1180.917,  1284.944,  1386.55 ,  1486.638,  1591.337,  1698.869,
         1804.891,  1916.978,  1971.259,  2144.813,  2306.129,  2482.079,
         2716.2  ],
       [  203.068,   281.462,   365.831,   452.459,   542.525,   642.014,
          741.469,   837.979,   933.94 ,  1031.774,  1128.684,  1234.403,
         1335.985,  1438.083,  1543.288,  1647.451,  1754.734,  1864.623,
         1977.717,  2092.776,  2203.563,  2348.758,  2537.179,  2729.067,
         2989.474],
       [  329.369,   411.577,   499.89 ,   591.454,   694.396,   801.534,
          900.967,  1001.657,  1100.112,  1210.446,  1313.982,  1419.177,
         1521.896,  1628.236,  1737.923,  1849.822,  1959.953,  2073.797,
         2189.87 ,  2310.498,  2443.827,  2612.493,  2833.738,  3061.671,
         3355.127],
       [  481.918,   567.878,   660.876,   757.359,   878.9  ,   983.608,
         1087.342,  1197.466,  1307.396,  1417.184,  1523.227,  1631.699,
         1746.193,  1855.747,  1968.289,  2082.471,  2198.554,  2316.823,
         2438.843,  2564.805,  2731.824,  2948.318,  3198.807,  3467.14 ,
         3803.649],
       [  657.852,   747.976,   845.947,   964.661,  1080.041,  1189.647,
         1305.57 ,  1422.41 ,  1533.366,  1646.615,  1762.328,  1878.454,
         1993.198,  2108.082,  2227.35 ,  2345.238,  2466.833,  2590.575,
         2717.829,  2876.309,  3083.597,  3344.686,  3638.714,  3950.464,
         4316.403],
       [  855.224,   949.457,  1052.059,  1185.073,  1303.727,  1415.895,
         1545.195,  1662.977,  1779.515,  1904.053,  2022.57 ,  2142.302,
         2265.464,  2384.989,  2508.393,  2631.948,  2758.714,  2888.587,
         3034.596,  3236.142,  3489.219,  3798.772,  4163.113,  4501.311,
         4933.351],
       [ 1072.5  ,  1170.968,  1278.185,  1422.689,  1543.209,  1674.609,
         1799.474,  1923.528,  2055.08 ,  2178.584,  2305.72 ,  2430.221,
         2557.131,  2682.837,  2809.758,  2941.35 ,  3072.539,  3212.386,
         3406.173,  3666.348,  3970.165,  4333.591,  4726.843,  5148.622,
         5647.449],
       [ 1308.563,  1411.091,  1544.233,  1677.859,  1803.793,  1943.961,
         2072.255,  2212.441,  2342.061,  2475.371,  2605.247,  2735.793,
         2868.495,  2999.629,  3134.109,  3267.516,  3408.876,  3580.003,
         3827.481,  4132.512,  4502.343,  4933.088,  5382.422,  5901.983,
         6427.202],
       [ 1562.572,  1669.124,  1815.181,  1948.874,  2091.406,  2230.169,
         2373.583,  2510.633,  2648.439,  2787.684,  2923.702,  3060.207,
         3197.339,  3334.873,  3474.962,  3617.988,  3769.462,  3994.645,
         4296.288,  4679.291,  5114.322,  5597.452,  6143.072,  6690.938,
         7323.501],
       [ 1833.935,  1944.412,  2100.744,  2233.938,  2388.496,  2529.578,
         2683.054,  2824.668,  2973.927,  3114.902,  3259.24 ,  3402.438,
         3545.653,  3689.284,  3834.629,  3984.456,  4173.12 ,  4469.078,
         4834.368,  5282.429,  5785.117,  6364.796,  6981.282,  7648.555,
         8360.27 ],
       [ 2122.236,  2236.648,  2401.51 ,  2536.625,  2701.081,  2856.573,
         3007.54 ,  3162.713,  3312.604,  3462.723,  3612.472,  3760.049,
         3909.245,  4059.32 ,  4214.651,  4378.03 ,  4622.687,  4982.705,
         5429.657,  5945.698,  6514.425,  7207.131,  7897.957,  8697.919,
         9551.63 ],
       [ 2427.263,  2545.431,  2718.436,  2868.048,  3028.51 ,  3195.535,
         3347.688,  3513.023,  3667.976,  3824.431,  3981.962,  4135.454,
         4290.544,  4449.576,  4609.125,  4798.588,  5118.657,  5543.64 ,
         6084.205,  6669.934,  7350.886,  8125.118,  8947.598,  9838.328,
        10851.726],
       [ 2748.863,  2870.943,  3049.388,  3212.428,  3373.837,  3546.071,
         3711.253,  3877.384,  4042.066,  4203.1  ,  4366.875,  4526.99 ,
         4689.806,  4854.603,  5026.215,  5274.257,  5661.144,  6169.734,
         6798.049,  7496.921,  8305.121,  9175.106, 10150.802, 11214.668,
        12424.548],
       [ 3087.111,  3212.815,  3395.726,  3568.644,  3733.623,  3912.828,
         4089.879,  4257.012,  4431.006,  4598.822,  4766.887,  4935.847,
         5105.436,  5280.265,  5464.715,  5777.978,  6250.964,  6872.678,
         7572.458,  8395.556,  9293.535, 10312.042, 11527.009, 12792.548,
        14307.565],
       [ 3442.126,  3571.236,  3759.172,  3940.308,  4118.177,  4296.198,
         4479.795,  4659.359,  4833.349,  5010.226,  5185.663,  5362.402,
         5539.836,  5720.805,  5939.726,  6342.373,  6901.963,  7625.563,
         8450.401,  9367.152, 10478.275, 11676.821, 13100.596, 14676.248,
        16572.307],
       [ 3814.176,  3946.602,  4138.667,  4328.553,  4514.597,  4694.962,
         4886.425,  5073.389,  5257.81 ,  5439.272,  5624.467,  5804.358,
         5990.571,  6182.441,  6451.291,  6945.533,  7604.223,  8437.149,
         9400.243, 10469.575, 11762.647, 13233.262, 14967.371, 17025.393,
        19898.502],
       [ 4203.529,  4357.572,  4535.921,  4734.082,  4927.06 ,  5119.494,
         5309.196,  5504.303,  5693.275,  5885.042,  6074.871,  6265.574,
         6460.063,  6662.972,  7015.869,  7596.406,  8379.211,  9308.886,
        10412.284, 11722.294, 13299.727, 15091.179, 17319.043, 20480.154,
        25378.806],
       [ 4610.621,  4778.871,  4950.512,  5155.46 ,  5355.934,  5556.771,
         5754.361,  5952.857,  6152.027,  6348.808,  6544.949,  6746.538,
         6950.223,  7167.989,  7608.983,  8306.829,  9213.261, 10290.979,
        11636.966, 13144.42 , 15038.195, 17396.949, 20741.447, 26078.762,
            0.   ],
       [ 5036.113,  5212.614,  5383.007,  5595.333,  5801.007,  6011.419,
         6215.739,  6419.994,  6625.051,  6829.73 ,  7035.631,  7243.069,
         7459.138,  7708.188,  8262.277,  9092.774, 10106.933, 11401.671,
        12950.701, 14837.004, 17199.912, 20557.699, 27350.611,     0.   ,
            0.   ],
       [ 5480.503,  5662.921,  5834.647,  6052.026,  6264.863,  6480.642,
         6693.308,  6905.99 ,  7118.233,  7331.522,  7544.547,  7761.907,
         7985.578,  8287.32 ,  8943.185,  9900.489, 11110.369, 12595.469,
        14433.653, 16758.525, 20071.65 , 26892.531,     0.   ,     0.   ,
            0.   ],
       [ 5944.52 ,  6131.707,  6317.354,  6527.954,  6747.774,  6969.669,
         7192.244,  7411.29 ,  7631.164,  7852.371,  8077.371,  8300.482,
         8534.611,  8919.084,  9696.428, 10798.074, 12240.721, 13958.569,
        16191.909, 19322.03 , 26110.835,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
            0.   ],
       [ 6429.058,  6620.759,  6816.688,  7023.934,  7251.042,  7479.638,
         7708.744,  7937.876,  8163.089,  8392.492,  8625.21 ,  8862.021,
         9106.545,  9585.334, 10502.633, 11809.174, 13453.518, 15532.814,
        18361.593, 23124.293, 27260.742,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
            0.   ],
       [ 6934.82 ,  7130.27 ,  7332.827,  7551.334,  7775.58 ,  8012.433,
         8247.07 ,  8483.467,  8718.151,  8955.23 ,  9196.392,  9441.61 ,
         9702.043, 10289.565, 11368.407, 12884.869, 14818.265, 17365.6  ,
        21225.574, 28430.656,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
            0.   ]]
y_train = data.reshape(data_rows,m1*m2)
```

Is there a way to have an output layer for matrices? I thought maybe a convolutional layer at the end? Or is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: can u paste the code?

Comment: What do you mean 0 start to appear in my data? Please be detailed.